# CSS Border transitions on selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created HTML table  and I want to make  "CSS Border transitions"  after the user clicks on the row (selected row ) and save the new border color to know this row is selected

like the first button with label "draw " in this URL

```
<i> http://codepen.io/giana/pen/yYBpVY/ </i>
```

but I can not do this can anyone help me, please

Comment: Plase post HTML and CSS reduced code sample so we have a look and help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the `:hover` styles to work when adding a class as well (*in my code `.active`*) and apply that class with javascript

so

```
  &:hover{
    color: $yellow;
  }
```

would become

```
  &:hover,
  &.active{
    color: $yellow;
  }
```

(*etc for all relevant `:hover` states*)

and the class would be toggled with this code

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active')
});
```

Updated demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/QNrgYM

Comment: I need effect start when I select row not on hover

Comment: in the demo you will notice that when you click on a button the effect stays. Disable the `:hover` and you will get the effect only on click.

Answer (score 0):

okay so I went into it a bit more and understand what yo are talking about simple take the code from this codepen and what I did was just remove on hover and everything is fine 
http://codepen.io/hobolandjacob/pen/MyGVpo

```
//Colors
$background: #fefefe;
$text: #4b507a;

$cyan: #60daaa;
$yellow: #fbca67;
$orange: #ff8a30;
$red: #f45e61;
$purple: #6477b9;
$blue: #0eb7da;

// Basic styles
button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px $red; // Using inset box-shadow instead of border for sizing simplicity
  color: $red;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;

  // Required, since we're setting absolute on pseudo-elements
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.draw {
    transition: color 0.25s;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    border: 2px solid transparent; // Set border to invisible, so we don't see a 4px border on a 0x0 element before the transition starts
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }

  // This covers the top & right borders (expands right, then down)
  &::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  // And this the bottom & left borders (expands left, then up)
  &::after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  &:hover,
  &.active{
    color: $cyan;
  }

  // Hover styles
  &:hover::before,
  &:hover::after,
  &.active::before,
  &.active::after{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &:hover::before,
  &.active::before{
    border-top-color: $cyan; // Make borders visible
    border-right-color: $cyan;
    transition:
      width 0.25s ease-out, // Width expands first
      height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s; // And then height
  }

  &:hover::after,
  &.active::after{
    border-bottom-color: $cyan; // Make borders visible
    border-left-color: $cyan;
    transition:
      border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, // Wait for ::before to finish before showing border
      width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, // And then exanding width
      height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s; // And finally height
  }
}

// Inherits from .draw
.meet {

  &:hover,
  &.active{
    color: $yellow;
  }

  // Start ::after in same position as ::before
  &::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  // Change colors
  &:hover::before ,
  &.active::before{
    border-top-color: $yellow;
    border-right-color: $yellow;
  }

  &:hover::after,
  &.active::after{
    border-bottom-color: $yellow;
    border-left-color: $yellow;
    transition: // Animate height first, then width
      height 0.25s ease-out,
      width 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
  }

}

// Does not inherit
.center {
  &:hover,
  &.active{
    color: $purple;
  }

  // Set up base styles, we're going to scale instead of animating width/height
  &::before,
  &::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transform-origin: center; // Ensure scaling is done from the center (expands outwards)
  }

  // scale3d(<scale-horizontal>, <scale-vertical>, <scale-depth>);
  &::before {
    border-top: 2px solid $purple;
    border-bottom: 2px solid $purple;
    transform: scale3d(0,1,1); // Shrink only width
  }

  &::after {
    border-left: 2px solid $purple;
    border-right: 2px solid $purple;
    transform: scale3d(1,0,1); // Shrink only height
  }

  &:hover::before,
  &:hover::after,
  &.active::before,
  &.active::after{
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1); // Show full-size
    transition: transform 0.5s;
  }
}

// Border spins around element
// ::before holds three borders that appear separately, one at a time
// ::after holds one border that spins around to cover ::before's borders, making their appearance seem smooth

.spin {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  padding: 0;

  &:hover,
  &.active {
    color: $blue;
  }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  &::before {
    border: 2px solid transparent; // We're animating border-color again
  }

  &:hover::before,
  &.active::before{
    border-top-color: $blue; // Show borders
    border-right-color: $blue;
    border-bottom-color: $blue;

    transition:
      border-top-color 0.15s linear, // Stagger border appearances
      border-right-color 0.15s linear 0.10s,
      border-bottom-color 0.15s linear 0.20s;
  }

  &::after {
    border: 0 solid transparent; // Makes border thinner at the edges? I forgot what I was doing
  }

  &:hover::after,
  &.active::after{
    border-top: 2px solid $blue; // Shows border
    border-left-width: 2px; // Solid edges, invisible borders
    border-right-width: 2px; // Solid edges, invisible borders
    transform: rotate(270deg); // Rotate around circle
    transition:
      transform 0.4s linear 0s,
      border-left-width 0s linear 0.35s; // Solid edge post-rotation
  }
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
}

.thick {
  color: $red;

  &:hover,
  &.active{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  &::before {
    border: 2.5em solid transparent;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  &::after {
    mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  &:hover::before,
  &.active::before {
    background: $red;
    border-top-color: $red;
    border-right-color: $red;
    border-bottom-color: $red;
    transition:
      background 0s linear 0.4s,
      border-top-color 0.15s linear,
      border-right-color 0.15s linear 0.15s,
      border-bottom-color 0.15s linear 0.25s;
  }

  &:hover::after,
  &.active::after{
    border-top: 2.5em solid $red;
    border-left-width: 2.5em;
    border-right-width: 2.5em;
  }
}

/* Page styling */

html {
  background: #1E202D;
}

body {
  //background: $background;
  color: $text;
  font: 300 24px/1.5 Lato, sans-serif;
  margin: 1em auto;
  max-width: 36em;
  padding: 1em 1em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  isolation: isolate;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much when I apply it on <table> not work on <table > tag on chrome could you help please

Comment: thank you very much when I apply it on tag <table> it did not work  on chrome could you help me, please

Answer (score 0):

Alright I added a table and fixed everything just surround everything that you want that effect in with button and it should work I remove the other css classes like SPIN and stuff just to keep it clean and focus on making it work http://codepen.io/hobolandjacob/pen/MyGVpo

```
<button class="draw">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td> 
      <td>Example</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This</td>
      <td>Is</td> 
      <td>TEST</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</button>
```

Comment: thank you very much but I need it on selected row, not on the table